# Where is a good place to start new activity when intercepted from URL

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser

I am intercepting URLs in my app using this in the Manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="myapp.com" android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So, in the `MainActivity.java`'s `onCreate` method I do this:

```
if (data == null) {
  //do regular stuff when app is opened by user in normal fashion.
} 
else {
 //do some activity when app is opened by the url intercepted
 Intent create = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SomeActivity);
 startActivityForResult(create, 1);
}
```

I am having some trouble with this approach which I'm still trying to iron out. But I wanted to ensure whether this is a good model to follow.

My basic requirement is: When the URL is intercepted, I want to `SomeActivity` to take over.